# Why EJS generates spaces between each iteration of a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

EJS generates spaces between each iteration of a forEach loop.

Here is my code :

```
   <tr>
        <th scope="row">Autre(s) demandeur(s) (membre)</th>
        <td>
            <% request.other_full_members.forEach(function (member, i){ %>
            <%= member.name%><% if (i !== request.other_full_member.length -1) { %>,<% } %>
            <% }) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And the result look like this :
[image]

This is not a problem for the display of the page. The problem comes when I want to export the table to .xlsx. The file is filled with unnecessary space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in your template are being displayed.
Try something like this:

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Autre(s) demandeur(s) (membre)</th>
  <td>
    <%
      request.other_full_members.forEach(function (member, i){
    %><%=
      member.name%><% if (i !== request.other_full_member.length -1) { %>,<% }
    %><%
      })
    %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was simple finally! I also tried to use -%> without success. According to the documentation : -%> Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline...